# How to understand the operation of this Python Sierpinski code?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have found this code on this website, and I have a few questions about it. I have already made a Sierpinski triangle on Python using my rudimentary knowledge and it is way too long and very bad.

I've done it using functions and some variables, but I have some questions with this code I have found. First of all, what is the "T" constantly brought up, the length and depth, and where is this all given a value. Where is the length and depth specified, and what does it do to the code?

Please note I am a beginner.

Here is the code:

```
import turtle
def draw_sierpinski(length,depth):
    if depth==0:
        for i in range(0,3):
            t.fd(length)
            t.left(120)
    else:
        draw_sierpinski(length/2,depth-1)
        t.fd(length/2)
        draw_sierpinski(length/2,depth-1)
        t.bk(length/2)
        t.left(60)
        t.fd(length/2)
        t.right(60)
        draw_sierpinski(length/2,depth-1)
        t.left(60)
        t.bk(length/2)
        t.right(60)

window = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
draw_sierpinski(100,2)
window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: If the answer solved your Question, consider setting the answer as accepted. So others who search for a similar problem, can find the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

`t` is an instance of the `class Turtle` located in the module `turtle` that is previously imported

```
import turtle
```

As the instance `t` is in the global scope the python interpreter is able to find it, even within the function `draw_sierpinski(length,depth)`

I have no idea where you obtained the code however here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle) for the turtle module.

To find out what the code does try it by yourself. Just `pip install turtle` and run the code

**From the turtle docs**

> Turtle graphics is a popular way for introducing programming to kids.
>   It was part of the original Logo programming language developed by
>   Wally Feurzig and Seymour Papert in 1966. Imagine a robotic turtle
>   starting at (0, 0) in the x-y plane. After an import turtle, give it
>   the command turtle.forward(15), and it moves (on-screen!) 15 pixels in
>   the direction it is facing, drawing a line as it moves. Give it the
>   command turtle.right(25), and it rotates in-place 25 degrees
>   clockwise.